# How to fix "Hash mismatch for chunk" error with iOS 13 + Apple On Demand Resources

Tags: swift, xcode, ios13

In my app I use Apple On Demand Resources.

I load the content with the following code:

```
currentRequest?.beginAccessingResources { (error: Error?) in
  if let error = error {
    onFailure(error as NSError)
    return
  }
  onSuccess()
}
```

This works well with iOS 12 and Xcode 10, however with the latest iOS 13 and Xcode 11, I get the following error:

> Begin: Request 0x0x283c498c0 response: Error: Error Domain=SZExtractorErrorDomain Code=4 "Hash mismatch for chunk containing offset 0: expected edf8721781dca63db1671ee3f0c7f199, got 621dea3aab25ce02a382f155971034c3" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Hash mismatch for chunk containing offset 0: expected edf8721781dca63db1671ee3f0c7f199, got 621dea3aab25ce02a382f155971034c3, SZExtractorActualHashValueErrorKey=621dea3aab25ce02a382f155971034c3, SZExtractorFileOffsetErrorKey=0, SZExtractorSourceFileLineErrorKey=470, SZExtractorFunctionNameErrorKey=-[StreamingUnzipState _checkHashForOffset:], SZExtractorHashChunkIndexErrorKey=0}`

I removed the assets, re-added them, tagged them, but the problem persists. What does this error mean?

Comment: I've seen this error as well. In general ODR seems to behave differently on iOS 13, I noticed that requests sometimes hang without any calls to the completion handler, also on a device. I've just had an app update rejected because of ODR installation problems – in this update the installation code wasn't touched, it used to work fine. The review was on 13.1.

So it looks like iOS 13 introduced some ODR-related regressions.

Comment: Hi @JanBerkel, I'm also experiencing a problem where the beginAccessingResources completion handler is not called (neither error nor succeed) on a test flight version for any iOS including 11 and 13. It was working the day before, then the next day it stopped working. Previous test flight version works though which narrows down to test flight's host service. We also have a version that uses our own host service with the same codebase which works. I will try to rebuild tonight as it takes more than 8 hours to process on the App Store with 6GB worth of resources.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have encountered this error as well while developing an application on an iPhone 6s with iOS 13.1.2 using Xcode 11.0. On Demand Resources were working fine, but after changing non-related code, the completion handler of `beginAccessingResourcesWithCompletionHandler:` of `NSBundleResourceRequest` errored out with a hash mismatch error. I presume that the error means to tell that the request was not able to fetch the resources that were expected, at least according to the resource hash, which leads to the conclusion that the problem does not stem from the resources, but the expected hashes.

To clear the expected hashes, I have deleted my App from the development device and after rebuilding and deploying, on demand resources load again without error.

Answer (score 1):

From our experience, the AppStore Review Team also encounters this error on their end from time to time. If you get a Rejection where the condition is caused by this error, tell them to remove the app from their device(s) before launching their tests again.

It might take a few attempts, but you'll eventually get a Reviewer that listens.

On-Demand Resource Management on iOS 13 appears to be wildly unreliable and prone to this hashing issue. The underlying issue is that the device is attempting to continue the download of a pending older version of the Asset Package and when attempting to merge the packets, it's encountering a hash that it is not expecting and breaking the file structure within the package.

Answer (score 0):

This error means the asset hash in the internal database doesn't match the hash of the asset downloaded from Xcode. One way this can happen is if you install your app through the store or TestFlight, then reinstall it in Xcode. The easiest fix is to delete the app from your device. If your device is jailbroken, you can run the following command through SSH:

```sh
sqlite3 /private/var/containers/Data/System/*/Documents/Persistence/storeSystem.db "delete from odr_asset_pack where bundle_key like 'app.ish.iSH.%'"
```